# How to unpack parameters in Python?

Tags: python, function, arguments, argument-unpacking

Is it possible to unpack parameters in python like in javascript?

```py
def foo([ arg ]):
    pass

foo([ 42 ])
```

Comment: Did you try running the code to see if it produces your expected results? You'd probably want to use `def foo( arg, *arg2):` that will unpack `arg2` as a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter unpacking was [removed in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) because it was confusing.  In Python 2 you can do

```
def foo(arg, (arg2, arg3)):
    pass

foo( 32, [ 44, 55 ] )
```

The equivalent code in Python 3 would be either

```
def foo(arg, arg2, arg3):
    pass

foo( 32, *[ 44, 55 ] )
```

or

```
def foo(arg, args):
    arg2, arg3 = args

foo( 32, [ 44, 55 ] )
```

Comment: Why they removed such a good part of a language? "Because it was confusing"? Really? If it confuses someone, why they just do not use this feature?

Comment: The reasons are [laid out in the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/#why-they-should-go).  They boil down to: it makes introspection tools harder to write, the error messages are difficult to debug, and no one was really using it anyways.

Comment: This is sad to see, coming from JavaScript. What a bad decision in my opinion.